# How do you access a variable returned from a previous task in a chain?

Tags: windows-8, c++-cx

I have the following task chain, where I want to access the variable `decoder` in the last task, but created in a much earlier task.

```
create_task(file->OpenReadAsync()).then([](IRandomAccessStream^ inStream) {
    return BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(inStream);

}).then([localFolder](BitmapDecoder^ decoder) {
    return localFolder->CreateFileAsync("map.png", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);

}).then([](StorageFile^ outFile) {
    return outFile->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::ReadWrite);

}).then([](IRandomAccessStream^ outFileStream) {
    return BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::PngEncoderId, outFileStream);

}).then([](BitmapEncoder^ encoder) {
    BitmapPixelFormat pixelFormat = decoder->BitmapPixelFormat; // how do I make decoder available here?
    // Do stuff that uses encoder & decoder
});
```

Comment: 1. That hurts my eyes, and 2. that's not C++, it's C++/CLI

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make it less hurtful to your eyes?

Comment: what do you think your benefit is to chain it like that? why not put all in one function and call that function in a task instead?

Comment: They are asynchronous operations with no equivalent synchronous functions, and I thought that it was best practice to chain the tasks rather than nest them.

Comment: Girls-gone-wild code to the C++ crowd and Ed, it is C++/CX code.  Which does not prevent you from storing an intermediate value in a field of your class so you can access it *later*.

Comment: See also [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) for the JavaScript equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just assigned the variables I needed to variables local to the function that contained the task chain.